# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Tags: android

android studio 2.3 giving error--

Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Comment: Does this also happen when building from the command line? Post your build.gradle files.

Comment: here's my gradle file-   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: `build.gradle` file**s**, all of them. Please add them *properly formatted* at the end of your question, it's unreadable in comments.